# tried to connect mongodb with my app getting an error

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

The error is **"MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string."**
I'm attaching ss of the file and the error [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIhNA.png)

the code in db.js(suubed in config folder) is

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const connectDB = async () => {
    try {
        const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            useFindAndModify: false
        })

        console.log(`${conn.connection.host}`)
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}

module.exports = connectDB
```

Comment: you're not including the environment file. `require("dotenv").config()` at the top. And install the package using `npm i dotenv`

Comment: are you using Heroku to host this? Or is this local?

Comment: also, try console.logging process.env.MONGO_URI to make sure it actually exists

Answer (score 0):

Please don't attach external links and/or screenshots - put the code right here.

As the error says, the "uri" (first parameter) to `mongoose.connect` is undefined, and needs to be a string -- make sure you're loading your environment variables successfully and make sure you didn't make a typo in the `process.env.MONGO_URI` variable name, since it currently evaluates to `undefined`.